# Duplicated and Distorted Fiducials

Tags: the-moon, apollo-program, photography

In the Apollo photographic record there are dozens of duplicated and distorted fiducials. They mostly occur on color images and when the camera is pointed directly at the sun or the sun is just out of the frame but it's flare is still visible on the image. Often you'll have a beautifully framed and composed image without duplicated fiducials followed by a mess of an image then a return to normality!

What causes this, isn't the reseau plate pressed close to the film? There are many examples but I'll just post snips from 3, thanks!

**EDIT**

It is generally confined to the brightest areas but there are inconsistencies. For example, this one from Apollo 13 where the sun is reflecting of the CM. There is a duplicated and askew fiducial above the centre of the reflection but the one below and closer the centre of brightness is normal. I don't know what those 2 curving parallel lines are to the right but they appear on half a dozen images in that magazine. Then there's this image from A14. The left fiducial is doubled and distorted but the right one appears unaffected. The antistatic electrode appears flipped and duplicated but smudged.

How did the flare surrounding the sun get that neat horizontal cut in its lower third? Why is the sun bulging (a common feature of sun up images, this is not the most extreme) beyond the borders of the frame? I don't think it's inter-reflections in the reseau plate or off the rear lens. I'm leaning more towards sloppy handling during processing and duplication.  [image]  [image]

[image]  [image][image]

Comment: Interesting, but not a question.  StackExchange is for questions and answers.  (You can self-answer questions if you want to introduce the community to something interesting, but you still have to hew to the question-and-answer format)

Comment: According to https://www.apollohoax.net/forum/index.php?topic=1917.0, the duplicates are reflections of the original fiducial marks or the rear element of the lens. What isn't mentioned (probably because it was thought to be "obvious") is that it occurs when a really bright light source is in or near the view, like the Sun :-).

Comment: I was once a keen silver halide photographer Is there a some document or paper describing the effect? There are so many different examples of this in all missions except 11 and it seems strange they didn't fix the problem. Why the down votes too? Shouldn't this be a place of open enquiry!

Comment: @ErinAnne ... "What causes this?" sounds like a question to me.

Comment: @Woody that was edited in after my comment. Funny thing: I checked back later, saw the same thing, and assumed I'd overlooked it until I checked the edit timestamp

Comment: @JohnHoltz thanks for the link to that site. I'm glad to see a bastion of rationality on the net.

Answer (score 2):

Have a look to the [Apollo Image Library:](https://www.hq.nasa.gov/alsj/main.html)

AS14-66-9306HR.jpg

[image: AS14-66-9306HR.jpg]

AS17-147-22579HR.jpg

[image: AS17-147-22579HR.jpg]

AS14-67-9387HR.jpg

[image: AS14-67-9387HR.jpg]

If you enlarge the images, the double crosses are visible within overexposed areas only. The double crosses are caused by reflection within the reseau plate.

Developing of the film could not cause such duplicated fiducials. Duplication faults would not be restricted to fiducials only, there should be other errors at the Lunar Module.

Answer (score 1):

Here is a higher resolution image of AS14-66-9306 and a collage of the four fiducial crosses closest to the sun glint. These factors point to (no pun intended) a reflection of the crosses within the camera:

- The duplicate crosses only appear near the glint. No other duplication is apparent in other crosses or the image.
- All the duplicate crosses are located radially outward from the glint. (Zoom in on the full resolution image to better see the arrows I have drawn from the duplicates through the originals.)
- The color of the duplicates is different: bluish versus reddish-brown for the originals.

[image: higher resolution]

Close-up of 4 crosses surrounding the glint. The line starts at the duplicate cross and passes through the original cross.
[image: close up of 4 crosses]